# How to query neovim API for the current working directory?

Tags: neovim

The [neovim API](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html) provides `nvim_set_current_dir()`, but apparently does not expose a way to query `cwd`. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that user12542635's answer is kind of correct, but it doesn't put the answer in the proper context of a python plugin, so I'll do so here. I suspect Rafael Quintela's answer is also correct, but I don't have a lua test environment set up, so I'll leave that to others to assess.

In the context of an nvim python [remote plugin](https://neovim.io/doc/user/remote_plugin.html), the following code will execute `pwd` in the nvim process, gather its result, and return it to the plugin process, where we can then instruct the nvim process to echo it:

```py
import pynvim
from pynvim.api.nvim import Nvim
from typing import List

@pynvim.plugin
class CwdPrinter:
    def __init__(self, vim: Nvim) -> None:
        self.vim = vim

    @pynvim.function("PrintCwd")
    def print_cwd(self, args: List) -> None:
        cwd = self.vim.command_output("pwd")
        self.vim.command(f"echo 'cwd: {cwd}'")
```

`PrintCwd` could then be called from nvim as `:call PrintCwd()`. This is obviously contrived; if one needed to print the current working directory, one should of course simply type `:pwd`, but it illustrates generally how to invoke remote vim commands in a plugin.

Answer (score 22):

old question, but I couldn't find the answer, so...
here it is; `:lua print(vim.fn.getcwd())`

> ps; if you're using lsp, you may want to put it on on_attach; `vim.api.nvim_set_current_dir(client.config.root_dir)`

Comment: Do you now the difference between `vim.loop.cwd()`?

Answer (score 3):

:help cwd yields

```
uv.cwd()                                                              *uv.cwd()*

                Returns the current working directory.

                Returns: `string` or `fail`
```

whereby `uv` is `vim.loop` from the UV Library https://docs.libuv.org/

therefore:

```
:lua print(vim.loop.cwd())
```

Works in NVIM v0.8.3

Comment: How to only get the name of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the regular Vim API that can be used for this:

```
getcwd()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. Per the link in my question, the API is a way to talk to neovim from plugins or external processes. I am attempting to query the nvim cwd from an external process, so I need a way to ask its API for that information.